# maven is not including required classpath file for javac

Tags: maven, javac

I'm working with maven and I'm developing 3 classes under the same parent pom though they belong to different actual projects.
The 3 classes belong to different pom file and artifact name and they are (outside their chained dependencies) completely independent.
For the sake of simplicity, I'll call them A, B and C.

A depends on B.
B depends on C.

A, at some point, makes a new instance of B.

```
...
B b = new B();
...
```

B extends C

```
...
public class B extends C {
...
```

here are the pom dependencies:
A:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

B:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

When I do a `maven install` on the parent pom file, it defines correctly the module order

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] C
[INFO] B
[INFO] A
```

First it compiles C and B correctly. Then, when It's time to compile A:

`/path/to/A/A.java[27,28] error: cannot access C`

If you are curious about what the "27,28" is, it is the line where the "new" that is quoted above above is.

The funny thing is:

1. If I do an `mvn install` on B first and then an `mvn install` on A (I know why ;)), it works but that's not a solution due to the requirements of the requested work.
2. If I add C to A's requirements, it also works. But it's not a solution as C is not a requirement of A, it is a requirement of B. If, for some reason, A stops using B, it makes no sense that whoever did that also has to remember to remove C from its requirements.

I forgot to mention:

For some reason, in the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ A ---
[INFO] my.group:A:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- my.group:B:jar:0.0.1:provided
```

C is not appearing as a requirement in the requirement tree. Although:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ B ---
[INFO] my.group:B:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] \- my.group:C:jar:0.0.1:provided
```

C is a requirement in the B's requirement tree.

**Main odd thing** is: Why isn't C in A's requirement tree?

Comment: In your Java code, show your package names and respective imports. Make these excerpts look like proper Java code. The show the paths for these source file. Show us an actual structure of the directories in your projects. (You're leaving way too much room for guess-work here and we're not all psychics).

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have declared B's scope as `provided` in A.  When the scope is `provided`, maven does not include the `transitive` dependencies.

Quoting from the [doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope),

> This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath,
>   and is not transitive.

Comment: AHA! So that's it! Thank you! By the way, considering that I don't want maven to add it to the classpath when it is executed (only when it is compiled) (please don't ask me the "why"). What is the alternative for me to use? Basically I want: " This scope is only available on the compilation classpath, and **is** transitive."

Comment: (meanwhile I'm searching for this)